# How to style the font in DropdownMenu Flutter items

Tags: flutter, enums, label, dropdown, overflow

I have a overflow problem in the list of items on my dropdown menu (print bellow). I'm trying to find a way to define font-size, or apply the overflow..
I followed the Flutter Doc from here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownMenu-class.html

The user can type in and search or simple select the item from the menu... All items come from a enum label... how can I style it (change font size, deal with the overflow etc..)?

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

/*-------Lista apenas de exemplo para o dropdown das malhas-------*/

enum MalhaLabel {
  
  malha1('010 dime: omissão de entrega'),
  malha2('NF-e: Cálculo: ');

  const MalhaLabel(this.label);
  final String label;
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final TextEditingController malhaController = TextEditingController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(70.0),

        /*-------AppBar com título-------*/

        child: AppBar(
          titleSpacing: 0.00,
          leading: Builder(
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer();
                },
                icon: const Icon(Icons.filter_alt_outlined),
              );
            },
          ),
          title: const Text(
            'AUDITORIA | MALHAS FISCAIS',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 18,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
          backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF1C5D22),
        ),
      ),

      /*-------Drawer com filtros-------*/
      drawer: Container(
        width: 350,
        child: Drawer(
          child: ListView(
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            children: [
              const SizedBox(
                height: 90.0,
                child: DrawerHeader(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Color(0xFF1C5D22),
                  ),
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Icon(
                        Icons.filter_alt_outlined,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 16,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'FILTROS',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 18,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),

              /*-------Filtros-------*/

              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20, top: 20),
                child: ListTile(
                  title: const Text(
                    'Malhas fiscais:',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                  ),
                  subtitle: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8),
                    child: DropdownMenu<MalhaLabel>(
                      controller: malhaController,
                      enableFilter: true,
                      requestFocusOnTap: true,
                      hintText: 'Digite e selecione',
                      dropdownMenuEntries:
                          MalhaLabel.values.map<DropdownMenuEntry<MalhaLabel>>(
                        (MalhaLabel malha) {
                          return DropdownMenuEntry<MalhaLabel>(
                            value: malha,
                            label: malha.label,
                          );
                        },
                      ).toList(),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Probably didn't notice there is an optional widget you can pass as a parameter inside

```
 DropdownMenuEntry<MalhaLabel>(   
    labelWidget:    
    )
```

Here you can customize how much width and height you need for fixing pixel overflow. If you want to elapse your text after a certain amount of characters you can do it inside this Text.

```
      return DropdownMenuEntry<MalhaLabel>(
                            value: malha,
                            labelWidget: SizedBox(
                                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.90,
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                  child: Text(
                                    malha.label,
                                  ),
                                )),
                            label: malha.label,
                          );
```

Here is your full code with my extended version, Copy/Paste this. It's working fine.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

/*-------Lista apenas de exemplo para o dropdown das malhas-------*/

enum MalhaLabel {

  malha1('010 dime: omissão de entrega'),
  malha2('NF-e: Cálculo: '),
  malha3('NF-e: Cálculo:'),
  malha4('NF-e: Cálculo2: omissão de entregaomissão de entregaomissão de entregaomissão de entregaomissão de entregaomissão de entregaomissão de entregaomissão de entrega'),
  malha5('NF-e: Cálculo2: omissão de entregaomissão de entregaomissão de entregaomissão de entregaomissão de entregaomissão de entregaomissão de entregaomissão de entrega');

  const MalhaLabel(this.label);
  final String label;
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final TextEditingController malhaController = TextEditingController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(70.0),

        /*-------AppBar com título-------*/

        child: AppBar(
          titleSpacing: 0.00,
          leading: Builder(
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer();
                },
                icon: const Icon(Icons.filter_alt_outlined),
              );
            },
          ),
          title: const Text(
            'AUDITORIA | MALHAS FISCAIS',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 18,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          ),
          backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF1C5D22),
        ),
      ),

      /*-------Drawer com filtros-------*/
      drawer: Container(
        width: 350,
        child: Drawer(
          child: ListView(
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            children: [
              const SizedBox(
                height: 90.0,
                child: DrawerHeader(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Color(0xFF1C5D22),
                  ),
                  child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Icon(
                        Icons.filter_alt_outlined,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 16,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'FILTROS',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 18,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),

              /*-------Filtros-------*/

              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20, top: 20),
                child: ListTile(
                  title: const Text(
                    'Malhas fiscais:',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                  ),
                  subtitle: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8),
                    child: DropdownMenu<MalhaLabel>(
                      controller: malhaController,
                      enableFilter: true,
                      requestFocusOnTap: true,
                      hintText: 'Digite e selecione',
                      dropdownMenuEntries:
                      MalhaLabel.values.map<DropdownMenuEntry<MalhaLabel>>(
                            (MalhaLabel malha) {
                          return DropdownMenuEntry<MalhaLabel>(
                            value: malha,
                            labelWidget: SizedBox(
                                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.90,
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                  child: Text(
                                    malha.label,
                                  ),
                                ),),
                            label: malha.label,
                          );
                        },
                      ).toList(),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello sir, thanks for the answer, but it still did not work. It puts the red underline on "labelWidget" and says: 

The named parameter 'labelWidget' isn't defined.
Try correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'labelWidget'.dartundefined_named_parameter

Comment: I've given the complete code, you can check it now.

Comment: Thanks again Abdul, I copy and paste but I still get the same thing. It puts a red underline under labelWidget.. with erro.. what it could be?

Comment: In the case of me, it's rendering perfectly.  Without any issue. Check that import of  (import 'package:flutter/material.dart';).

Answer (score 0):

Try below snippet for dropdown,

```
      DropdownButton(
              isExpanded: true,
              value: selectedValue,
              onChanged: (newValue) {
                //LOGIC HERE
              },
              items: items.map((item) {
                return DropdownMenuItem(
                  value: item,
                  child: Text(item, overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis, maxLines: 1),
                );
              }).toList(),
            ),
```

Happy Codding..!

Comment: I'm using DropdownMenu, not DropdownButton. like the flutter docs sample: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownMenu-class.html

Answer (score 0):

I've updated the previous version to use `DropdownMenu` and customized the hint text and dropdown menu items. Additionally, I've extracted a couple of customization styles into separate functions:

```dart
TextStyle get _fieldStyle {
  return const TextStyle(
    color: Colors.deepPurple,
    fontSize: 18,
  );
}

TextStyle get _itemStyle {
  return const TextStyle(
    fontSize: 16,
    color: Colors.purple,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
  );
}
```

Please note the customization for hint text and dropdown menu items, as well as the special attention to `MenuStyle? menuStyle` and `ButtonStyle? style` for further style management elements.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: DropdownDrawerScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class DropdownDrawerScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const DropdownDrawerScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<DropdownDrawerScreen> createState() => _DropdownDrawerScreenState();
}

class _DropdownDrawerScreenState extends State<DropdownDrawerScreen> {
  final fruitController = TextEditingController();
  String? selectedFruitName;

  final List<String> fruits = [
    'Apples are sweet and very crunchy, perfect for a healthy snack',
    'Bananas are yellow, rich in potassium, and ideal for breakfast',
    'Cherries are small, red, absolutely delicious, and great for making pies',
    'Dates are sweet, chewy, very nutritious, and excellent for energy bars',
    'Elderberries are dark, tart, and good for syrups, with strong antioxidant properties'
  ];

  TextStyle get _fieldStyle {
    return const TextStyle(
      color: Colors.deepPurple,
      fontSize: 18,
    );
  }

  TextStyle get _itemStyle {
    return const TextStyle(
      fontSize: 16,
      color: Colors.purple,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w300,
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    fruitController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Dropdown in Drawer Example')),
      body: const Center(child: Text('Choose an option from the drawer')),
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: ListView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          children: [
            const DrawerHeader(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.blue),
              child: Text(
                'Choose a fruit',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 24),
              ),
            ),
            _buildMenu(),
            OutlinedButton(
              onPressed: () => fruitController.clear(),
              child: const Text('Clear'),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildMenu() {
    return LayoutBuilder(builder: (_, ctx) {
      final size = ctx.biggest;
      final width = size.width;
      return DropdownMenu<String>(
        controller: fruitController,
        label: _buildHintText(),
        textStyle: _fieldStyle,
        enableFilter: true,
        requestFocusOnTap: true,
        expandedInsets: EdgeInsets.zero,
        menuStyle: MenuStyle(
          fixedSize: MaterialStatePropertyAll(size),
        ),
        width: width,
        onSelected: (String? value) {
          setState(() {
            selectedFruitName = value;
          });
        },
        dropdownMenuEntries: fruits.map((value) {
          return DropdownMenuEntry<String>(
            value: value,
            label: value,
            labelWidget: Row(
              children: [Expanded(child: _buildItemText(value))],
            ),
            style: ButtonStyle(
              fixedSize: MaterialStatePropertyAll(size),
            ),
          );
        }).toList(),
      );
    });
  }

  Widget _buildHintText() {
    return Text(
      'Select your favorite fruit',
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.purple[100], fontSize: 16),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildItemText(String value) {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 8),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(4, 8, 4, 8),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(color: Colors.black38),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
      ),
      child: Text(
        value,
        style: _itemStyle,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm using DropdownMenu, not DropdownButton. like the flutter docs sample: api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownMenu-class.html

Comment: I'm edited that answer